# I am using flask ,flask_sqlalchemy paginate function works fine for page1 but it's not working for other page

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am connected to existing **Ms Access** data base.And my model looks like

```
class Suppliers(db.Model):

   __tablename__ = 'Suppliers'
   SupplierID = db.Column('SupplierID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   __table_args__ = {'autoload': True,'autoload_with': db.engine}
   def __repr__(self):
      return f"Suppliers('{self.SupplierID}', '{self.SupplierName}')"
   def as_dict(self):
      return {"SupplierID": self.SupplierID, "SupplierName": 
          self.SupplierName}
```

In the views my query works well only  with page=1,but it is not working when page is more than 1 i.e when page=2;Paginate query returns all the item instead of item from 20 to 39(when page=2, per-page=20) and so on

```
 "sArgs": {"searchString": "sometext","searchPage": 1, "perPage": 20, "orderBy": "SupplierName"}

queryResults = Suppliers.query.filter(Suppliers.SupplierName.like('%'+sArgs['searchString']+'%'))
               .order_by(asc(sArgs['orderBy']
                )).paginate(
                page=int(
                    sArgs['searchPage']
                    ), per_page=sArgs['perPage']
                )
```

But its not working when :
"sArgs": {"searchString": "sometext","searchPage": 2, "perPage": 20, "orderBy": "SupplierName"}.

Same works fine when I use **sqlite DB.**
I am not able to find out what is the problem here.Please help me to find the solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I see the situation when you are searching for the first page, which you told us is working correctly. Can you show us sArgs in the case when it's not working correctly?

Comment: its not working for example : "sArgs": {"searchString": "sometext","searchPage": 2, "perPage": 20, "orderBy": "SupplierName"}     ; paginate returns all the items from table instead of only 20 record .

Comment: Are all records retrieved? Or are there all records returned except the first 20? Are you sure that the queryResults you have specified is always considered? Is it possible that it's only considered in the case of a GET request and you are sending a POST request? I'm just guessing here and of course could be wrong.

Comment: Its returning all the record, It  as 2000+ records in it. And its getting only GET request and I m not doing POST. When parameter to paginate is page=2,per-page=20 is passed;resulting queryResults has page=2,per_page=20,prev_num=1 etc..  but queryResults .items as all the 2000+ records in it, including first 20

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it's running at all. First line of your query should be `Suppliers.query.filter(Suppliers.SupplierName.like('%'+sArgs['searchString']+'%'))`. `like` is a method of the column, not the query, and you also had an extra right parenthesis. This probably won't solve your problem but it'd make your example correct.

Comment: did you try max_per_page parameter , If page or per_page are None, they will be retrieved from the request query. If max_per_page is specified, per_page will be limited to that value. If there is no request or they aren’t in the query, they default to 1 and 20 respectively Source : https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination

Comment: @bkerivan thanks for the correction ; I have used it properly in my query I posted  it wrong in the above example .

Comment: @redhatvicky yes,I tried using max_per_page also but not working

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating a simple table using mysql which has a primary key as ID and a Name which contains some city names , tried to filter the Records using the same logic and i am able to get it done , here below is the snippet for the same . Kindly check whether this could resolve your issue, The only difference from your snippet is that i have mentioned "max_per_page" parameter and i have mentioned the entity name with model name directly with like . The Snippet looks something like the below.

```
queryResults = City.query.filter(City.name.like("%as%")).order_by(asc("name")).paginate(page=2, error_out=False, max_per_page=15)
```

Complete Snippet :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import asc

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://***:***@***/***'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<City Name %r>' % self.name

queryResults = City.query.filter(City.name.like("%as%")).order_by(asc("name")).paginate(page=2, error_out=False, max_per_page=15)

result = dict(datas=queryResults.items, 
                   total=queryResults.total, 
                   current_page=queryResults.page,
                   per_page=queryResults.per_page)

print(result)
```

Output :

```
{'datas': [<City Name 'Ashdod'>, <City Name 'Ashgabat'>, <City Name 'Ashikaga'>, <City Name 'Ashoknagar-Kalyangarh'>, <City Name 'Ashqelon'>, <City Name 'Asmara'>, <City Name 'Assuan'>, <City Name 'Astana'>, <City Name 'Astrahan'>, <City Name 'AsunciÃ³n'>, <City Name 'Asyut'>, <City Name 'Ã\x81guas Lindas de GoiÃ¡s'>, <City Name 'Bandar-e-Abbas'>, <City Name 'Banjarmasin'>, <City Name 'Barasat'>], 'total': 232, 'current_page': 2, 'per_page': 15}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Sorry i forgot to mention Same code works with Sqlite database.I dont know why its not working when it is connected to  MS access .I have already tried using max_per_page but does't work with that too.(also  i have mentioned the entity name with model name directly with like)